# stopPropagation does not work in a hierarchy of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-table, stoppropagation

I am trying to avoid an `onClick` event that is on each particular row, whenever show/less is being clicked under one column's data. I have a grid that basically has select, and multi select features. Also there is show more/show less for one of the column. Whenever I click on `Show More/Less`, the row selection is triggered. I want to avoid this. Can someone tell what is wrong here. say If a have multiple instances of similar grids, I would want the row select functionality to that grid which has prop in it

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-alternate-single-row-working-5fr81

```
 import * as React from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

export default class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedRows: []
    };
  }

  rowClick = (state, rowInfo) => {
    if (rowInfo) {
      let selectedRows = new Set();
      return {
        onClick: e => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          if (e.ctrlKey) {
            selectedRows = this.state.selectedRows;
            rowInfo._index = rowInfo.index;
            if (
              selectedRows.filter(row => row._index === rowInfo._index)
                .length === 0
            )
              selectedRows.push(rowInfo);
            else
              selectedRows = selectedRows.filter(
                row => row._index !== rowInfo._index
              );
            this.setState({
              selectedRows
            });
          } else {
            selectedRows = [];
            rowInfo._index = rowInfo.index;
            selectedRows.push(rowInfo);
          }
          this.setState(
            {
              selectedRows
            },
            () => {
              console.log("final values", this.state.selectedRows);
              this.props.rowClicked(this.state.selectedRows);
            }
          );
        },
        style: {
          background:
            this.state.selectedRows.some(e => e._index === rowInfo.index) &&
            "#9bdfff"
        }
      };
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactTable
        data={this.props.data}
        columns={this.props.columns}
        getTrProps={this.rowClick}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In your opinion what is the advantage of omitting braces in these inner if-blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your ShowMore component, you can modify your `onClick` event handler to call `event.stopPropagation()`. This will stop further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases, and allow you to click on Show More/Less without triggering row selection.

```
const toggleTruncate = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  setShowMore(!isShowMore);
}
```

React actually defines the synthetic event, which will be available on your click event handler, without the need to call `document.addEventListener()`. You may read more about event handling in React over [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

And answering your second part of the question, given that the `rowClicked` event is an optional props of the `DataGrid` component, you will need to manually check it on the `DataGrid` component to ensure that it will only be called if it is defined. This is how it can be done:

```
if (rowClicked) {
 // do the rest
}
```

And this is how your `rowClick` method should look like. Do take note that I have [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props object on the second line. This will ensure that row selection logic will be carried out only if `rowClicked` is defined.

```
rowClick = (state, rowInfo) => {
  const { rowClicked } = this.props;
  if (rowInfo && rowClicked) {
    let selectedRows = new Set();
    return {
      onClick: e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
          selectedRows = this.state.selectedRows;
          rowInfo._index = rowInfo.index;
          if (
            selectedRows.filter(row => row._index === rowInfo._index)
              .length === 0
          )
            selectedRows.push(rowInfo);
          else
            selectedRows = selectedRows.filter(
              row => row._index !== rowInfo._index
            );
          this.setState({
            selectedRows
          });
        } else {
          selectedRows = [];
          rowInfo._index = rowInfo.index;
          selectedRows.push(rowInfo);
        }
        this.setState(
          {
            selectedRows
          },
          () => {
            rowClicked(this.state.selectedRows);                
          }
        );
      },
      style: {
        background:
          this.state.selectedRows.some(e => e._index === rowInfo.index) &&
          "#9bdfff"
      }
    };
  } else {
    return "";
  }
};
```

Comment: that did work:) Also there is one more part left. Say If a have multiple instances of similar grids, I would want the row select functionality to that grid which has prop in it

Comment: Hmm.. I realised that you did not use the `rowClicked` props on both of the `DataGrids` defined on your index.js? Only one of them has that `rowClicked` prop

Comment: yes but on both   grids , row select functionality is being applied. But I want that feature only when I pass it a prop from that grid. Tried adding check     if (this.props.rowClicked) {} inside DataGrid rowClick() but not working

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-alternate-single-row-working-5fr81 . Check the sandbox I have updated with your answer. Still second grid has the row selection feature . It should not have it since it has got no prop

Comment: Ohh I see.. The rows should not be selected if the `rowClicked` prop is not passed?

Comment: yes yes the grids which has rowClicked as the prop should have that row selection feature

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205539/discussion-between-wentjun-and-v2103).